# Как заменить строку с map() на списочное выражение?

Tags: python, list, список

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

как заменить эту строку на списочное выражение, такого же функционала(эта строка записывает неограниченное кол-во чисел через пробел)

Comment: Вы хотите считать числа через пробел без использования Map?

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да равно так же

```
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```